# How to interpret the generator statement: if ($current%3 == 0 && $current%5 == 0)

Tags: php, generator

I'm working my way through the PHP and MySQL Web Development book by Welling & Thomson.

There's a sample piece of code on generators (Listing 6.5 pg 193):

```
<?php

function fizzbuzz($start, $end)
{
  $current = $start;
  while ($current <= $end) {
    if ($current%3 == 0 && $current%5 == 0) {
      yield "fizzbuzz";
    } else if ($current%3 == 0) {
      yield "fizz";
    } else if ($current%5 == 0) {
      yield "buzz";
    } else {
      yield $current;
    }
    $current++;
  }
}

foreach(fizzbuzz(1,20) as $number) {
  echo $number.'<br />';
}
?>
```

---

I know in line 7 it means if divisible by 3 or 5 yield "fizzbuzz." However, when I look at it I interpret the line as (if current variable is divisible by 3 and equal to zero "and" if current variable is divisible by 5 and equal to zero).

If it were equal to zero then it wouldn't be divisible by 3 or 5. However, the code works. So does the == 0 part mean equally divided by 3 or 5 with no partial numbers leftover?

Answer (score 1):

% means modulus. You divide and take the remainder and then afterward see whether that remainder is equal to zero. If A % B == 0, then A is evenly divisible by B.

Some examples:
7 % 2 = 1
10 % 4 = 2
100 % 4 = 0
37 % 19 = 18
3337 % 78 = 61

On that line it means "If current is divisible by 3 AND also divisible by 7".

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! The == 0 part was throwing me off.

Answer (score 0):

I think I see where you go wrong. The statement `$current % 3 == 0` (I've added a couple of spaces for readability) really says "$current modulus 3 equals 0."

We use the modulus function to determine if something is divisible with no remainder, and that happens when the result is zero. In other words...

```
1 modulus 3 = 1
2 modulus 3 = 2
3 modulus 3 = 0
4 modulus 3 = 1
5 modulus 3 = 2
6 modulus 3 = 0
```

As you can see, the result is only zero when the number is evenly divisible.

Comment: This took a little google searching to understand 2 modulus 3 = 2. It's quite interesting that it's not .666; if it's not fully divisible the first number (dividend) remains. It also makes sense, if you wanted .666 you'd just divide it. Such a cool feature, abstract, but I can see some great uses for it once I get better at PHP. thank you.

Comment: @trevorpan Yes, 2 divided into 3 indeed yields 2/3 or .666, but modulus is the _remainder_ function. So how many "threes" are there in the value two? None, and the whole thing is the remainder. Consider 20 modulus 3. The division result is 6.666, but the modulus is still 2 because 20 is evenly divisible by 3 six times, leaving 2 over.